# Image Outlining Effect in .NET

Tags: c#, image

I'm looking to accomplish the following effect in C#:

[alt text http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/1530/conversionj.png](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/1530/conversionj.png)

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a fairly standard edge detection algorithm. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) has some info on that. There are quite a few algorithms:

- [Canny edge detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector)
- [Sobel operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator)
- [Roberts cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberts_Cross)
- [Prewitt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prewitt)

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [AForge Image Processing Library](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/)

[Here's a project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx) that will enable you to determine if AForge Image Processing is what you need.

Try doing a Floyd-Steinburg Binarization and then a Homogenous Edge detection... or some combination thereof.

Answer (score 1):

I know your asking about C#, but if you don't find an existing C# implementation - perhaps you could port [this](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/EdgeFilter.html) to C#.  It's written in Java, but it's open source. Having some code to start with seems like it would be nice.

There are [multiple](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html) other filters also...

Here is their result:

[image: Result]
<sub>(source: [jhlabs.com](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/EdgeFilter2.jpg))</sub>